# Need some help creating a podio calculation

Tags: podio

I am trying to create an inventory system in podio. I have an app that with two relationships, my users, and my inventory.

I am trying to create a calculation that will show the available inventory that is available to loan out. I am trying to count how many current records that have an item attached then subtract that from my on-hand. I have tried to bring @all of and loop through but am having trouble counting the total products that have been assigned out. Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

in a calculation field you do only need to loop for counting if @all of item-field.length is not giving you the exact count.

example loop :

```
var stat3 = @All of Exch Status
var statNumber3 = stat3.length;
var count3 = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < stat3.length; i++){
if(stat3[i] == "TODO"){
++count3;
}};
```

sure this code can be better/nicer but it works ... ;-)